# How to reset to factory settings after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, restore, windows-8-refresh

I was given a computer from someone else who upgraded recently. The one they gave me is running Windows 10 Pro (They upgraded from Windows 8). I'd like to restore it to factory settings, even if that means back to Windows 8, I can always upgrade again afterwards. But every time I try to restore it using the option to in settings I get the blue screen and it restarts. Is there any reason it shouldn't work because of the Windows 10 upgrade? They don't have the original installation media or licence key otherwise I would just do a clean install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reset to factory settings is to reinstall Windows 10 using the ISO. The ISO can be obtained from https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

With regards to concerns on windows 10 activation after wiping out the hard drive you can refer to the following link for more information

http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-tweaks-activation-rules-for-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/

Answer (score -1):

Source - http://www.in.techradar.com/how-to/computing/How-to-factory-reset-a-laptop/articleshow/51683674.cms

Gist of article

While PC is booting and windows loading screen hasn't come yet, quickly tap F8 many times. An Advanced boot options menu should appear. At this point ,select repair and press enter. Login with username and password. At this point you'll see a menu titled "System recovery options". Generally at the end you should see a link to manufacturers recovery software. CLick it and it will restore to the original state of system from a hidden disk image on the drive.